# Etymology of Verschränkung?

Tags: etymology, scientific-language

I don't really have much German but I'm very interested in this word.  Schrödinger used it to describe entanglement, also providing the English.

I was wondering if it might relate to versch. (various?)

- Interested both in the German words Verschränkung is based on, and also the etymology of those words all the way back to the PIE if possible.

*Links to any online Germanic lexical resources would also be appreciated!*

Answer (score 8):

> I sense that **versch (various?)**, but that's as far as I've gotten.

I'm assuming you're thinking of *verschieden* here. You didn't analyze that quite correctly. *Ver-* is a very common German verbal prefix that has a multitude of different meanings as you can see [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ver-#German). In the case of *(Quanten)-Verschränkung*, we have a nominalized version of the verb *[verschränken](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/verschr%C3%A4nken)* (*to cross your arms*), which is in itself derived from the noun *[Schranke](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Schranke)* (gate, barrier).

Comment: To add to this: *verschieden* is related to *(unter-)scheiden* which means to separate, to differentiate.

Comment: And the meaning has left the realm of *gate, barrier* of course and went into the realm of arms tied to each other.

Comment: aah.  thanks.  yup, I was just guessing with versch!  Could a literal translation be to "cross a barrier" re: space (aka "spooky action at a distance")?

Comment: @Janka, you have the etymology the wrong way around.

Comment: @DukeZhou: No, the meaning is *entangled*. Overcoming a barrier or entanglement would be ***ent**schränkt*. You won't find this word in a dictionary — but *beschränkt*, and as *be-* and *ent-* are in opposition, people would understand what *entschränkt* should mean.

Comment: @Janka thanks for that. Do you know of any online etymological resources for German.  Trying to get a sense of any classical & PIE roots.

Comment: Wiktionary is a good place to start, it links its sources: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/verschr%C3%A4nken

Comment: @DukeZhou, https://dwds.de/wb/Schrank#et-1, but you would have to know some German.

Comment: @Janka wiki appears to be insufficient in this case, but I found this [Etymological Dictionary
of Proto-Germanic](https://www.bulgari-istoria-2010.com/Rechnici/A_Lyubotski_Proto_Germanik_dict.pdf)   *i <3 the internet*

Answer (score 6):

Verschränkung is derived from the noun **Schranke**, which means barrier or limit. The often red and white bar blocking passage over trains rails is also called *Schranke*.

With the picture of the railroad crossing in mind, when you cross your arms over your belly, we call it "die Arme verschränken".

The bridge to **Verschränkung** in quantum physics comes from the idea, that 2 things are entangeled in a way so that you can't operate on one, without influencing the other. In the case of crossed arms you notice that you will never find a single arm the same position, when the other arm is not involved.

Another possible english translation for Verschränkung is interlocking, which could have been another english name for the phenomenon, except that the entangled particles in quantum physics can be locally separated.

According to https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/verschraenken it goes back to **forscrenchan** in Old High German, which means something like **to surround with a barrier** or **lock in**.

Comment: Beautiful answer.  Do you know if goes back further than Middle High German?